# ¿ Como insertar y mostrar datos de un arreglo dentro de otro arreglo?

Tags: java, array

Estoy programando un ejercicio en Java para el cual tengo que crear una empresa inmobiliaria que tiene una serie de clientes, los cuales tienen en venta unas viviendas.

Hasta ahora los datos de los clientes los estoy guardando en un arreglo. De momento todos los datos eran del tipo String,  pero ahora tengo que guardar dentro de clientes las viviendas con sus propios datos, dirección, precio etc.

Tengo claro que debo de añadir los datos de la Viviendas en un arreglo , igual que hice con los Clientes. Lo que no estoy seguro es de si tengo que guardar el arreglo de Viviendas dentro del arreglo de Clientes, o guardar Viviendas en un arreglo independiente, ya que cada cliente tiene un numero de Viviendas.
En principio he añadido el arreglo viviendas en el constructor de Cliente, para pasar el arreglo de viviendas por parametro, <strike>aunque esto no sé hacerlo aún.</strike>

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Ya he logrado añadir un arreglo Viviendas a un arreglo Cliente, y lo he hecho añadiendo como parametro el arreglo Viviendas a Cliente desde el constructor.

> <strike>Imagino que para añadir las Viviendas tendré que hacer un metodo y con >un bucle "for" recorrer el arreglo al igual que he hecho con el arreglo de >Clientes , pero no sé si tengo que hacerlo en un "for anidado " dentro del >arreglo de Clientes o por separado.</strike>

Efectivamente así era, **la solución a mi problema era hacer dentro del bucle for del arreglo Clientes otro bucle for para el arreglo de viviendas y finalmente añadiendo el arreglo viviendas "v" a la clase Cliente.**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Introduce Nombre: ");
        nombre = entrada.nextLine();
          // Bucle que rellena el areglo de viviendas
          for (int j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce Direccion: ");
              direccionVivienda = entrada.nextLine(); 
                v[j] = new Vivienda(direccionVivienda);
                  in.agregarVivienda(v[j]);
          }
          c[i] = new Cliente(nombre,v); 
          in.agregarCliente(c[i]);
    }
```

> <strike>Tampoco sé como debo de programar el metodo de agregar y mostrar >viviendas y si los metodos deben de ir en la clase Cliente o en la clase >Inmobiliaria.</strike>

> En principio pensaba hacerlo igual que he hecho con Clientes, ya que los metodos >de agregar y mostrar Clientes que iban en la clase Inmobiliaria, se pueden usar >igual para agregar y mostrar viviendas, pero en este caso los metodos de agregar >y mostrar viviendas los he puesto en la clase Clientes y creo que no funciona.

Los metodos agregarCliente y mostrarCliente los he dejado en la clase Inmobiliaria.

Finalmente muestro la informacion en pantalla con el metodo toString desde la Clase Cliente y añadiendo el arreglo viviendaVenta con Array.toString:

```
public String toString() {
        return " Cliente: " + " Nombre: " + nombre + Arrays.toString(viviendaVenta);
    }
```

Al final quedó así :

**Clase Principal**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombre, direccionVivienda;
    Inmobiliaria in = new Inmobiliaria();
    Vivienda v[];
    v = new Vivienda[1];
    Cliente c[];
    c = new Cliente[1];
    // Bucle que rellenar el arreglo de clientes
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Introduce Nombre: ");
        nombre = entrada.nextLine();
          // Bucle que rellena el areglo de viviendas
          for (int j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce Direccion: ");
              direccionVivienda = entrada.nextLine(); 
                v[j] = new Vivienda(direccionVivienda);
                  in.agregarVivienda(v[j]);
          }
          c[i] = new Cliente(nombre,v); 
          in.agregarCliente(c[i]);
    }
    in.mostrarCliente();
  }
}
```

**Clase Cliente:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Cliente {
  
  private String nombre;
  private Vivienda viviendaVenta[];
  
  public Cliente() {
    this.nombre = "";
    this.viviendaVenta = new Vivienda[10];
  }
   public Cliente(String nombre, Vivienda[] viviendaVenta) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.viviendaVenta = viviendaVenta;
  }

  public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
  }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
  }

  public Vivienda[] getViviendaVenta() {
        return viviendaVenta;
  }

    public void setViviendaVenta(Vivienda[] viviendaVenta) {
        this.viviendaVenta = viviendaVenta;
  }

  @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " Cliente: " + " Nombre: " + nombre + Arrays.toString(viviendaVenta);
    }

  


}
```

**Clase Vivienda :**

```
public class Vivienda{
  private String direccion;
  
  public Vivienda() {
    this.direccion = "";
  }
   public Vivienda(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
  }

  public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
  }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
  }

  @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " Vivienda: " + " Direccion: " + direccion;
    }

  


}
```

**Clase Inmobiliaria:**

```
public class Inmobiliaria { 
    
    private Cliente clientes[];
    private Vivienda viviendas[];
    
    public Inmobiliaria() {
        clientes = new Cliente[100];
        viviendas = new Vivienda[10];
        
    }

    public Cliente[] getClientes() {
        return clientes;
    }

    public void setClientes(Cliente[] clientes) {
        this.clientes = clientes;
    }
    public Vivienda[] getViviendas() {
        return viviendas;
    }
    public void setViviendas(Vivienda[] viviendas) {
        this.viviendas = viviendas;
    }
    
    public void agregarCliente(Cliente c) {
        boolean encontrado = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < clientes.length && !encontrado; i++) {
            if (clientes[i] == null) {
                clientes[i] = c;
                encontrado = true;
            }
        }
        if (encontrado) {
            System.out.println("Cliente Añadido");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se ha podido añadir el cliente");
        }
    }

    public void mostrarCliente() {
        for (int i = 0; i < clientes.length; i++) {
            if (clientes[i] != null) {
                System.out.println("Fila: " + i + clientes[i].toString());
            }
        }
    }
    public void agregarVivienda(Vivienda v) {
        boolean encontrado = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < viviendas.length && !encontrado; i++) {
            if (viviendas[i] == null) {
                viviendas[i] = v;
                encontrado = true;
            }
        }
        if (encontrado) {
            System.out.println("Vivienda Añadida");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se ha podido añadir la vivienda");
        }
    }
}
```

Seguiré con el ejercicio , espero que al final esto sirva de ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: La cantidad de clientes de la inmobiliaria por lo que veo, siempre será 2. Y la cantidad de viviendas de los clientes, si se usa el constructor por defecto, será 10. Estos números tienen una razón de ser? Pregunto para poder recomendarte otras estructuras de datos en caso de que el nro de viviendas y clientes de tu problema puedan ser flexibles

Comment: @AndresGardiol La cantidad de viviendas o clientes tendrá un limite que irá en una variable aunque de momento habia indicado esas cantidades a modo de prueba. Sé que comparado con los array o arreglos , hay otras estructuras que podrían ser mejores para almacenar objetos, como el arraylist pero aún no lo hemos dado en clase y tengo que usar los arreglos convencionales.

Comment: @JoseJordan, si has conseguido arreglarlo, no edites la pregunta con la respuesta... una pregunta ***es y siempre deberá ser*** una *pregunta*, las *respuestas* deben ser *respuestas* para que la gente pueda encontrarlas! Eres libre de responder a tu propia pregunta, de hecho, te animo a hacerlo! Pasadas unas horas (24h, creo) podrás incluso marcarla como respuesta aceptada!

Comment: @Benito-B Ups! volví a editar el post incluso antes de ver su comentario, lo siento.